# executescript chrome extension not executing properly

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to get the values into the elements on the new tab and then click submit to login.
I have tried many variations and just can't seem to get it to work.

```
function injectScript(){
var script =  ' var e = document.getElementById("email"); var p = document.getElementById("password");'+
              'e.value ="'+currentEmployee.email+'"; p.value = "'+currentEmployee.password+'";'+
              'var osbut = document.getElementById("osLoginButton"); osbut.submit();';

chrome.tabs.create({ url: "https://www.example.com" });

  chrome.tabs.executeScript({
    code: script, runAt :"document_start" // i have tried document_idle and document_end too
  });
//https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-executeScript

}//end func
```

Heres what the button looks like that I am targeting to submit

```
<button type="submit" id="osLoginButton" class="btn btn-block" 
ng-disabled="!user.email || !user.password || loggingIn" 
style="background:#6f5092; color:white; width:75%; 
display:block; margin-right:auto; margin-left:auto; margin-top:2rem;"><span>
&nbsp;&nbsp;</span><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in pull-left"></span>Sign me in</button>
```

Here is the error I am getting on the new tab in console

```
Unchecked runtime.lastError while running tabs.executeScript: Cannot access a chrome:// URL
    at injectScript (chrome-extension://ihekknfdfleelcebfjflficdnebfadlc/popup.js:188:15)
    at empLogin (chrome-extension://ihekknfdfleelcebfjflficdnebfadlc/popup.js:177:1)
    at HTMLAnchorElement.<anonymous> (chrome-extension://ihekknfdfleelcebfjflficdnebfadlc/popup.js:160:42)

    error in extension
```

Is it possible the script is targeting the extension? The new tab page is running angular1. I am not sure if that ng-disabled is affecting it because it takes time for the angular to change and the script is failing because of that. I also can't test that because there are no setTimeouts in extensions. Though 
I did try to send a setTimeout() inside the executed script, nothing worked. I am at a loss.
And no, I cant change the button on the page of the new tab. Thankyou for your help ahead of time.

Comment: The API is asynchronous so you need to executeScript in the callback of tabs.create using the `tab` parameter passed to that callback, and specify `tab.id` in executeScript's first parameter. See the documentation.

Comment: I thought that the tab.id was optional and it defaulted to the current tab which would be the new tab. I will try to add the inject script as the callback though and see if that works. Thankyou, I will give it a try

Comment: "Current" means at the moment the code runs, and executeScript runs *before* the tab is actually created because the API is asynchronous.

Comment: Unchecked runtime.lastError while running tabs.executeScript: Cannot access a chrome:// URL
    at Object.callback (chrome-extension://ihekknfdfleelcebfjflficdnebfadlc/popup.js:189:15)              
Thats what  I am getting now when I did chrome.tabs.update({url:'https://www.example.com/login'}, function(){
chrome.tabs.getCurrent(function (Tab){
  chrome.tabs.executeScript(Tab, {
    code: script, runAt :"document_end"
  });
  });

 });

Comment: No, getCurrent returns the tab that runs your extension code as explained in the documentation. I've already told you you need to use the tab parameter of the callback. You can wait for someone to post a proper answer or look at [demo extensions](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/samples).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of the chrome extension APIs are asynchronous, you need to wait for a tab created callback.

`chrome.tabs.create({
    url: 'https://www.example.com'
}, function (tab) {
    chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, {
        code: 'code to inject...'
    });
});`

Comment: Your format makes sense, can you look at my script var at the top to see if there is something wrong there. I still can't get this to execute properly. I tried with your format and still not filling in fields and submitting.

Comment: I followed your format and tried to inject just a console.log and cant get that working. Let alone my actual script. Any ideas?